# python random numbers from list (x.difference)

Tags: python, list, random, difference

hey there is there anyway to simplify this code, all I want to do is to create and list of 128 numbers (2^7) and each time it loops it chooses 18 from the list and after 8 times it should had covered all the numbers.

Thanks

```
x = set(range(0x00,0x81))
test_patterns0 = random.sample(x,16)

z = x.difference(test_patterns0)
test_patterns1 = random.sample(z,16)

y = z.difference(test_patterns1)
test_patterns2 = random.sample(y,16)

q = y.difference(test_patterns2)
test_patterns3 = random.sample(q,16)

r = q.difference(test_patterns3)
test_patterns4 = random.sample(r,16)

s = r.difference(test_patterns4) 
test_patterns5 = random.sample(s,16)

t = s.difference(test_patterns5)
test_patterns6 = random.sample(t,16)

p = t.difference(test_patterns6)
test_patterns7 = random.sample(p,16)
```

Comment: not 18,  16 numbers each time, 16*8 = 128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle a list of unique values with `random.shuffle()`, then iterate through it in groups of 16.

Comment: Here you are with 8 values shuffled and split into groups of 4. You can generalize to your specific problem... `>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
>>> import random;
>>> random.shuffle(mylist);
>>> mylist;
>>> mylist[0:4];
>>> mylist[4:8];
`